# Работа с <meta name="viewport">

Tags: html, viewport

При начальной загрузке с мобильного устройства сайт открывается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно пользоваться обратным зумом чтобы привести его к такому состоянию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прописал такой viewport чтобы чтобы контент не сворачивался в адаптивный (так сказать)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1070, initial-scale=1">
```

добился того что на скринах, но не понял как задать начальное масштабирование в 1070рх ширины, то есть чтобы он сразу выглядел как на втором скрине
если в `initial-scale` ставить `auto` то масштаб становится слишком мелким, как будто сайт открыт на 1920

Answer (score 2):

`initial-scale=1` уберите из мета-тэга.

Выглядеть будет так: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1070">`

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1070, initial-scale=1">
```

Данный мета-тег задаст минимальный размер окна в 1070px

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1070, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Данный мета-тег установит минимальный и максимальный размер окна и ограничит уровень масштабирования, более подробно можете почитать
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Вроде соседний ответ правильнее. Ему нужно 1070, а не единичный масштаб.